# How to run streamlit multi-command in VS Code regardless of default terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash, streamlit

I have the [Multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension installed on VS Code and use it to launch Streamlit apps using this configuration in settings.json which is run via a keyboard shortcut:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.streamlitActiveFile",
        "label": "Streamlit: Run Active File",
        "description": "Streamlit run active file in active terminal",
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                "args": {
                    "text": "streamlit run ${relativeFile}\u000D"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This has worked fine thus far while I have been using the standard command prompt on a Windows machine. Now I've changed to using Git Bash as my default terminal, and the command above fails because the relative file path is passed as a Windows path with backslashes, and Git Bash can't parse that:

```
$ streamlit run visuals\streamlit\time_plot.py
Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...
Try 'streamlit run --help' for help.

Error: Invalid value: File does not exist: visualsstreamlittime_plot.py
```

In short, the backslashes are ignored and the path becomes a single file name instead. I'd like some way to be able to launch Streamlit apps using a multi-command via a keyboard shortcut, and I'm open to either of these solutions, or something else I haven't considered:

- Send a relative file path that can be parsed correctly regardless of which terminal is the default terminal.
- Launch a Windows command prompt even when Git Bash is the default terminal, and activate the Streamlit app there.
- Change the working directory to the directory containing the streamlit file (again regardless of which terminal is the default terminal) and launch the file there without having to give a path.

Comment: Would this alternative approach help? (https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-run-your-streamlit-apps-in-vscode-3417da669fc)

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to work me. The configuration works in debug mode, but not for running the files normally. There it produces a totally different command than what the blog post shows.